# Calling/monitoring JVM via JMX from a non java client

Tags: jvm, monitoring, jmx

I am using Nagios for monitoring - and looking at NPRE for various monitoring on a given box. I have some java processes - would be nice to "peek into them" via JMX etc.. I can't see a way to do this without starting up a JVM and connecting remotely?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can connect to JMX services via [RMI-IIOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RMI-IIOP), which I believe is CORBA for Java.  I believe this means you can use any COBRA client to connect to a RMI-IIOP Java service.  Check out [JBoss IIOP](http://jboss.org/jbossiiop), which does what you want, I believe, only it's JBoss-specific.

Perhaps it might be easier to simply wrap the JMX services you wanna export using JAX-WS or JAX-RS (i.e., as web services)? Then you can use plain ol' HTTP to access what you want.

In fact, [it seems someone has done exactly that](http://blogs.oracle.com/jmxnetbeans/entry/restful_access_to_jmx_instrumentation)!  I presume you would like access to something like:

- `http://<host>:<port>/rest/jmx/java.lang:type=Memory/NonHeapMemoryUsage/commited`

The entire project is available at https://opendmk.dev.java.net/contributions/rest-adaptor/readme.html :

> **Restful JMX Adaptor**
>
> This Project
> OpenDMK contribution offers an HTTP
> access to JMX information in a RestFul
> way. An article published in [the JMX
> NetBeans blog](http://blogs.oracle.com/jmxnetbeans), covers in detail the
> approach.

Another (the same?) project is available at https://ws-jmx-connector.dev.java.net/

Comment: heh - I ended up doing a simple ad-hoc version of the RESTful thing by accident (a few lines of code) but that is good to know ! I wasn't insane after all !

Answer (score 2):

For monitoring JMX with Nagios [jmx4perl](http://search.cpan.org/~roland/jmx4perl/) is the perfect solution since it comes already with a feature rich Nagios Plugin [check_jmx4perl](http://search.cpan.org/~roland/jmx4perl/scripts/check_jmx4perl). It uses [Jolokia](http://www.jolokia.org), an agent which bridges JMX via JSON/HTTP and has advanced features like fine grained security or bulk request which are not available for classical JSR-160 connectors. It is also being actively developed, whereas the REST approaches described above seem to be stuck in the year 2008 (this was also a reason for starting jmx4perl in May 2009). BTW, JSR-262 "Web Services Connector for Java Management Extensions (JMX) Agents" has unfortunately the status "inactive" since some time, so I don't expect much progress from this side.

Comment: Good to know, thanks. I quite like nagios and it has proven to be very trustworthy.